# How to prove following inequality?

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

> Q)Show that if any chord on the graph of function $$y=f(x)$$ lies
>   higher than the subtended arc,then there exists the following
>   inequality:$$\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}>f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)$$ for all
>   $$x_1\ne x_2$$

I tried doing this with the help of : $$\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2} =f(c), x_1<c<x_2$$but couldn't go any further.
I couldn't devise a method using Lagrange's mean value theorem and and couldn't do it by comparing slopes of chord and the any point on the graph.Also I couldn't prove,(which I thought could lead to answer)$$f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)<f(c); x_1<c<x_2 $$
How should I solve this?

Comment: You can compare the values of $f$ and that of the line joining $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and  $(x_1,f(x_1))$ (you can easily get its equation) at the midpoint $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$.

Comment: Are you aware that *“any chord on the graph of function ... lies higher than the subtended arc“* is the definition of a (strictly) convex function?

Comment: The chord joining $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$ is a *linear* function. What values does it take at $x = (x_1+x_2)/2$?

Comment: @MartinR yes I am aware of that.But I wish to prove it mathematically as it has been asked as a question in one of my assignment.

Comment: @MartinR $$\frac{(3x_1-x_2)f(x_2)+(x_2-x_1)f(x_1)}{2(x_2-x_1)}$$. Not sure how to proceed further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The end points of the chord are $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$ The co-ordinate of the mid point of the chors is $[\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}, \frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}]$
Since the chord is above the curve then $$\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2} \ge f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right).$$